# Ansible Jinja to_json filter multiline and pretty formatted

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, ansible-filter

I am creating a JSON file by converting some YAML to json using `to_json` filter for example as follows

```yaml
- name: Create JSON file
  copy:
    content: "{{ some_ansible_dict_var|to_json(ensure_ascii=False) }}"
    dest:  /tmp/content.json
```

The `to_json` filter seems to always create the json content in one line. Is there a way to pretty format the content over multiple lines with indentation etc ?

Comment: is `to_nice_json` not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `to_nice_json` filter. It is documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json).
You can specify the indent as well: `{{ some_ansible_dict_var | to_nice_json(indent=2) }}`