# PIcking JSON objects out of an arbitrary text file

Tags: json, ansible, scripting

I need to execute regular functionality tests on something over 10,000 linux nodes. I can adapt ansible to do it by [creating several custom facts](https://medium.com/@jezhalford/ansible-custom-facts-1e1d1bf65db8) and then [dumping a node's entire set of facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839509/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-ansible-pre-defined-variables), including the custom `ansible_local` facts, into a [pretty JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931370/ansible-jinja-to-json-filter-multiline-and-pretty-formatted). Each node will generate its own file, and the resulting text files looks something like this:

```
HOSTVARS (ANSIBLE GATHERED, group_vars, host_vars) :

{
   [[ VALID JSON OBJECT ]]
}

PLAYBOOK VARS:

{
    [[ VALID JSON OBJECT ]]
}
```

I can script a bunch of razzle-dazzle with `sed` and whatnot to split up the text file. But with the number of nodes I'll be scanning and reporting on, going through those steps will blow up the wall time of any wrapper script I write. I'd rather just teach the JSON parsing script to recognize that some non-JSON text is also in the source file and to ignore that.

What methods exist for teaching Python, or another language, to scan a complex or arbitrary text file for JSON objects and them assembling those objects into definable dictionaries?

Comment: Why all in one file? Have each instance dump to its own file/database entry/etc and scan them regularly.

Comment: If the non json text has enough regularity to it, you could run a regex over the file to strip the unwanted bits and write whatever is left.

Comment: @Ouroborus - I will be getting a facts file for each node, and each node will create its file in the described format. I can experiment with only getting HOSTVARS or PLAYBOOK VARS, but that's still going to leave me with a JSON object and extra text outside that object. However much I tidy the facts dump, I don't think ansible is going to just give me a JSON object.

Comment: @jwdonahue - In the absence of a better idea, that's probably what I'll do and take the performance penalty. Since I want to keep the original output for archiving and forensics, I'd probably loop each node's facts file to a temporary file, cut the lines I don't want, and parse the rest. Therein lies my blown up wall clock...

Comment: Why not just generate a file that is valid JSON?

Comment: @larsks - I'm getting the file the way ansible gives it to me. If you know of a way to get ansible to give me just a JSON object, that counts as a valid solution to this question.

Comment: Ansible doesn't "give you" files. You choose the format of your output by what you place into your templates. Take a look at my answer for one option and see if that does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you're not simply generating valid JSON output to begin with, saving you from all that weird parsing after the fact. Something like:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        all_my_vars:
          host_vars: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"
          playbook_vars: "{{ vars }}"

    - delegate_to: localhost
      copy:
        content: |
          {{ all_my_vars|to_nice_json }}
        dest: "./reports/{{inventory_hostname}}.json"
```

This will generate one file per host in a local directory named `reports`. Each file contains a JSON dictionary that has two top-level keys, `host_vars` and `playbook_vars`. The contents are what you would expect.

Comment: Thank you! This is enough to get me on the right track. As to "why you're not simply generating valid JSON," maybe add your solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839509/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-ansible-pre-defined-variables, as well. That's were my initial attempt came from.